# 'Affine' object does not support item assignment (rasterio)

Tags: rasterio, transform, affine

I would like to change the resolution of cells in the transform slot of a raster file, but it seems I cannot just do that with simple variable re-assignment.

```
import rasterio 

ftdm = rasterio.open(dtm_path)
profile = fdtm.profile
profile['transform'][0] = 0.25
```

I get this error:

```
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
TypeError: 'Affine' object does not support item assignment
```

How can I override it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify the raster, you either need to open in `r+` mode or `w` mode depending on if you wish you create new raster or modify inplace

Using `r+`

```py
ftdm = rasterio.open(dtm_path, 'r+')

ftdm.transform =  ftdm.transform * ftdm.transform.scale(
    your_new_value_here/ftdm.transform[0], 1
    )

ftdm.close()
```

The first and second argument of `scale` method modifies pixel width and height
respectively.

---

If you do not wish to change the original raster, you could also try the following

```py
ftdm = rasterio.open(dtm_path)
new_transform = ftdm.trasnform
new_profile = ftdm.profile
ftdm.close()
new_profile.update(transform = new_transform * new_transform.scale(your_new_value_here/new_transform[0], 1)
```

The above code will alter your `profile` but not the original raster.

If you wish to change other values of transformation matrix, search for `shear`, `translation` and `rotation` method as described [here](https://pypi.org/project/affine/).

Comment: Thanks - this is what I was looking for (changing the profile without changing the raster).